# Do anchors and aliases in YAML store the string or the interpolated string?

Tags: yaml, circleci

When I run the following job on CircleCI the cache key mysteriously changes between the cache being read and the cache being written. The only explanation I can think of is that my understanding of anchors and aliases in YAML is incorrect.

I'm using a YAML [anchor and alias](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/writing-yaml/) to capture the cache key when I read it and then to read it back when I write it. And yet somehow the two keys are different (as if the line is being re-evaluated).

```
commands:
  npm_install:
    description: Install and cache (cached) node modules
    steps:
      - restore_cache:
          key: &NPM_CACHE_KEY v8-npm--{{ .Branch }}-{{arch}}-{{checksum "~/project/angular/package-lock.json"}}

      - run:
          name: Install Node modules
          command: |
            cd ~/project/angular
            npm install ci

      - save_cache:
          key: *NPM_CACHE_KEY
          paths:
              - ~/project/angular/node_modules/
              - /usr/local/bin/node_modules
              - /home/circleci/.cache/
```

The result of running this is the following:

[image]

Zooming in on the cache key lines you can see that the cache key is different.

```
# When reading the cache
v8-npm--add_angular_version_display-arch1-linux-amd64-6_85-IXQLtfeuATYKtD1dRoCJu_FbRnfhYZb1+XkVFRET5Pc=

---

#When writing the cache
v8-npm--add_angular_version_display-arch1-linux-amd64-6_85-0wC66hCG9ZcSN9wfW4NlpxQswHV+n4foEcQ15cWRxqg=
```

### Does the YAML anchor/alias method save the interpolated or un-interpolated string?

Leaving aside the question of why the `package-lock.json` file might have changed in the first place there's another question. Why are these two keys different? Is the YAML being re-interpolated?

Is what's being saved to `&NPM_CACHE_KEY`, the interpolated value, i.e. `v8-npm--add_angular_version_display-arch1-linux-amd64-6_85-IXQLtfeuATYKtD1dRoCJu_FbRnfhYZb1+XkVFRET5Pc=`

or... is it saving ``NPM_CACHE_KEY v8-npm--{{ .Branch }}-{{arch}}-{{checksum "~/project/angular/package-lock.json"}}` and re-evaluating this the second time round?

### If anchors/aliases re-interpolate then what doesn't?

If the anchor is re-interpolating then how can I get it to simply store the output?

(I also have another problem which is why the hash of package-lock is changing but that's a separate problem)

Comment: `npm install ci` installs [a package named `ci`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ci), and only incidentally the other dependencies, hence the change to the lockfile; I think you mean `npm ci`. `v8-npm--{{ .Branch }}-{{arch}}-{{checksum "~/project/angular/package-lock.json"}}` is being filled in by CircleCI, the value actually in the YAML contains the placeholders - run it through e.g. http://www.yamllint.com/ to see how it gets expanded.

Comment: @jonrsharpe wow, good spot on the ci, that was a glaring error! And you made a really good point about seeing how it gets expanded, I used CircleCI's `compiled` view and it was in fact re-evaluating.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the anchor stores the *template for the interpolation* and not the *interpolated string*.

I discovered this by using @jonrsharpe's suggestion to look at the expanded version of the config file. You can view this inside CircleCI and when viewed it was very clear that the problem was that it is being re-interpolated.

```
# Expanded view snippet of config.yml

- restore_cache:
        key: v8-npm--{{ .Branch }}-{{arch}}-{{checksum "~/project/angular/package-lock.json"}}
    - run:
        name: Install Node modules
        command: |
          cd ~/project/angular
          npm ci
    - save_cache:
        key: v8-npm--{{ .Branch }}-{{arch}}-{{checksum "~/project/angular/package-lock.json"}}
        paths:
        - ~/project/angular/node_modules/
        - /usr/local/bin/node_modules
        - /home/circleci/.cache/
```

(NB the reason the checksums were different was that I should have been going `npm ci` and not `npm install ci` as I was actually doing).